# Why is my program returning empty dataframe using sqldf

Tags: python, pandas, sqldf

The below code is returning empty dataframe. The reason am using case statement is : if there is mismatch in stat_id_cd between stat_genius and stat_npps, it populates with the delimiter. The below code was working for a single row but not for more than one row.

Below is the dataframe stat_genius followed by stat_npps dataframe

| POL_REF_NO | POL_NUM | STAT_ID_CD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MPK100 | MPK1000 | 4A |
| MPK100 | MPK1000 | 4B |

Below is the second dataframe.

| POL_REF_NO | POL_NUM | STAT_ID_CD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MPK100 | MPK1000 | 4A |
| MPK100 | MPK1000 | 4B |

```
stat_result = sqldf('''
select 
   a.POL_REF_NO
   , a.POL_NUM
   , CASE     
      WHEN a.STAT_ID_CD = b.STAT_ID_CD THEN a.STAT_ID_CD
      ELSE a.STAT_ID_CD||' | '||b.STAT_ID_CD END AS STAT_ID_CD 
FROM stat_genius a  
JOIN stat_npps b on b.POL_REF_NO = a.POL_REF_NO and b.STAT_ID_CD = a.STAT_ID_CD''')

print(stat_result)
```

Comment: What result are you getting with more than one row?

Comment: @Barmar  an empty dataframe

Comment: That makes no sense. The columns in the `SELECT` list shouldn't affect how many rows are returned. That just depends on the join and where clauses.

Comment: What do you get if you just do `SELECT a.POL_REF_NO, a.POL_NUM, a.STAT_ID_CD, b.STAT_ID_CD FROM ...`?

Comment: We don't have your full code. A SELECT statement only pulls in the needed columns.   If your code is not producing syntax errors and you are getting 0 returned records, you may need to look at how the data is being pulled into a data frame. Validate your data frame with `df.head()` to ensure the code is actually pulling the data into the target data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try a LEFT JOIN instead. Research all types of joins so you understand how they work.

Comment: No `WHERE` clause means to return all rows.

Comment: @tdelozie Yah tried them. for left join its returning none under stat_id_cd